# Connection String in Azure while using Spring Boot

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, azure-java-sdk

I can see that we can define a secure connection string form portal, and than can access those variables in our application.I found many examples to do it in ASP.NET, like defining the keys in web.config. But i can not find any example focusing on accessing these connection strings defined via portal from Spring Boot app. 
Any help in that direction would be useful

Comment: Hi Amit, take a look here https://buildazure.com/2015/11/30/azure-web-app-application-settings/ and here https://buildazure.com/2015/12/01/azure-web-app-connection-strings/ . As Spring Boot is a Java style app you can find an example under the Java section. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I was looking looking for something like this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Azure exposes these secure strings as environment variables, you can name them to override application properties using the following format:

Property name `my.secret.password` can be overriden with environment variable `MY_SECRET_PASSWORD`.

You can also use them directly in your `application.properties`

```
my.secret.password=${SUPER_SECRET_ENV_VARIABLE}
```

Answer (score 2):

See this article from **Stefan**: [How Application Strings and Connection Strings Work in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/)

Azure app service exposes them in the form of environment variables at runtime to the web app. There is a naming convention in place which makes it easier to retrieve them.

For **app settings** the name of the corresponding environment variable is prepended with **`APPSETTING_`**. For connection strings, it depends on the type of DB that has been configured. See below

- For **SQL Azure** it is **`SQLAZURECONNSTR_`**
- For **SQL Database** hosted on **Azure VM** it is **`SQLCONNSTR_`**
- For **MySQL database** it is **MYSQLCONNSTR_**
- For any other type of databases it is **CUSTOMCONNSTR_**

In Java, you can use the `System.getenv()` function to retrieve the environment variables. Refer the document on how to use this: [public static String getenv(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv--)

You can pass the environment variable to this function to get it working. For example

```
String envStr = System.getenv("APPSETTING_TestSetting");
```